# Failed to set ENV variables in docker containers via Dockerfile at build stage

Tags: ubuntu, docker, fedora

I would like to set http proxy and https proxy to a docker container while building it. Hence I configured it with `ENV` keywords at the begining of the Dockerfile. Something like this

```
FROM hub.docker.example.com/fedora:25

ENV http_proxy=http://example.com:911
ENV https_proxy=https://example.com:912


RUN \
  .
  .
  my tasks, download something which need proxy
  .
  .

ENTRYPOINT sleep infinity
```

But when I run the container and check with command `ENV | grep proxy`, there is no proxy being set. Am I doing anything wrong on the Dockerfile?

*It's a fedora image

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the documentation this is clearly mentioned.

> If your container needs to use an HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP proxy server,
>   you can configure it in different ways:

- In Docker 17.07 and higher, you can configure the Docker client to
  pass proxy information to containers automatically.

**Configure the Docker client**

> On the Docker client, create or edit the file ~/.docker/config.json in
>   the home directory of the user which starts containers. Add JSON such
>   as the following, substituting the type of proxy with httpsProxy or
>   ftpProxy if necessary, and substituting the address and port of the
>   proxy server. You can configure multiple proxy servers at the same
>   time.

so using this method you get rid of older methods.

**When you create or start new containers, the environment variables are set automatically within the container**

```
   {
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

**For older version**

> When you build the image, or using the --env flag when you create or run the container, you can set one or more of the following variables to the appropriate value. *This method makes the image less portabl*e,

[image]

Comment: I think he's not trying to create it in cli, but in Dockerfile. So, ENV in Dockerfile better than --env in cli, although they produces the same.
Furthermore, his proposal is not about HTTP servers. HTTP server is a consequence, because the fact is an issue about ENV variables in Dockerfile which apparently are not in the container after.

Comment: share your exact dockerfile may be remove in some intermediae layers

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked your issue with fedora and ubuntu and ENV are set.
I don't understand your steps but I can post mine, clearly separated so you could tell me if there's something wrong in which of them:
My Docker file looks as follows:

```
FROM fedora

ENV http_proxy=http://example.com:911
ENV https_proxy https://example.com:912

ENTRYPOINT sleep infinity
```

After that, which takes lastest Fedora, build image executing in the same directory you have the Dockerfile:

```
docker build -t yourimagename .
docker run -d --name yourcontainername yourimagename 
docker exec -ti yourcontainername bash
```

Check environment variables with `env`, not `ENV`:

```
env | grep http
https_proxy=https://example.com:912
http_proxy=http://example.com:911
```

> Definitively, you are defining ENV correctly in your Dockerfile. Furthermore, you could also would define them without '=' sign. Both are correct:

```
ENV http_proxy=http://example.com:911
```

OR

```
ENV http_proxy http://example.com:911
```

Comment: That is an image provided by my organisation. I logged in to that container with `run -it <image> /bin/sh` and try command `import`, it shows that `command not found`. Is this causing me from setting the environment variable?

Comment: `ENV | grep proxy` was a typo :)

Comment: What about pulling image? `docker pull hub.docker.example.com/fedora:25` does work? Let's try step by step from the beginning

Comment: Pulling image was success, hence i can see the image with `docker images` and it's able to start & exec too.

Comment: Do you have any http_proxy configuration in other steps in your Dockerfile which could rewrite ENV? Could you try the same Dockerfile without intermediate steps?
ARGs are only available in build step but ENV should persist after container start.

Comment: No other arguments being passed. I use command `docker build -t fedora .` to build the container. There is only 1 action under RUN  which is `curl -o filename123`. Forgot to mentioned, i have proxy config for docker client under `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`, but i dont think this causing the failure.

Comment: Could  you post exactly command to build image and container? If you execute docker build you're not building container.
Try to do: 
`docker build -t anothernamenotfedora .`
`docker run -ti anothernamenotfedora bash` 

It looks you're creating container from another image, from original fedora instead image you're built with your Dockerfile.